# How to write this formula in model builder or raster calculator?

Tags: modelbuilder, raster-calculator

I'm trying to calculate the following formula for each pixel of my raster but I have no idea how to do it -

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression should be something like this -

```
0.077 * (2.71828 ^ ( (1.209*"layer@1") - (1.739*"layer@2") + (0.412*"layer@3") - (5.198*("layer@3"/"layer@1")) + (10.408*("layer@2"/"layer@1")) ) )
```

Where *2.71828* is an approximate value of *e* and *layer* refers to your raster layer and the number after '@' refers to the band number.

Refer this link for guidance on using Raster Calculator in QGIS - 
https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_analysis.html#raster-calculator

Comment: its working in qgis but not for arcgis .when im trying to load the result in arc i get inconsistent extent error :(

Comment: Refer this [link](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm) for ArcGIS